# Max across fields and return field title

Tags: sql, max, lookup, teradata

I have a query result that looks like this:

```
    EMAIL   Business    Cars    CookingDIY  EntertainmentFashion    Family  French  Golf    HealthFitness   HomeGarden  Kids    NewsCulture Photography ScienceTech Spanish
1   duck@gmail.com  0   0   1   4   0   0   0   6   0   1   0   0   0   0
2   cat@gmail.com   9   18  0   1   0   0   0   0   18  0   19  0   17  0
3   dog@nl.gmail.com    0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   bird@gmail.com  4   3   0   2   1   0   1   5   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   goat@gmail.com  1   0   3   7   2   0   0   1   2   0   1   0   0   0
```

I would like to SELECT the max category for each record. So, the first record above, duck@gmail.com would have EnterntainmentFashion (4) returned in the new field. The second record would have NewsCulture (19) returned.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why does the first row return EntertainmentFashion(4) when HealthFitness(6) is the Max?

Comment: Sorry yes you are right, it should read HealthFitness for record 1

Comment: Looks like you have to `UNPIVOT` to achieve your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you get that result, looks like a pivot query.

If you just want three columns as result, mail - category - count, you simply undo the pivoting and use a ROW_NUMBER:

```
select email, interest, count(*)
from tab
group by 1,2
qualify 
   row_number() over (partition by email order by count(*) desc) = 1
```

**Edit:**

Based on your previous questions this is probably a pivot query based on LIKE, so there's no easy way to remove the pivot...

What's your TD release?

In TD14 there's a GREATEST function, but it's limited to 10 values, so you have to nest it:

```
case 
   when Business =   greatest(greatest(Business,Cars,CookingDIY,EntertainmentFashion,Family,French,Golf,HealthFitness,HomeGarden),greatest(Kids,NewsCulture,Photography,ScienceTech,Spanish)) then 'Business ('   || trim(Business)   || ')'
   when Cars =       greatest(greatest(Business,Cars,CookingDIY,EntertainmentFashion,Family,French,Golf,HealthFitness,HomeGarden),greatest(Kids,NewsCulture,Photography,ScienceTech,Spanish)) then 'Cars ('       || trim(Cars)       || ')'
   when CookingDIY = greatest(greatest(Business,Cars,CookingDIY,EntertainmentFashion,Family,French,Golf,HealthFitness,HomeGarden),greatest(Kids,NewsCulture,Photography,ScienceTech,Spanish)) then 'CookingDIY (' || trim(CookingDIY) || ')'
...
end
```

Before you need to use a monstrous CASE :-(

But if you don't need all those columns, just the one with the maximum, you could join to a table with all the LIKE wildcards before the count:

```
create volatile table interests(interest varchar(30), wildcard varchar(30)) on commit preserve rows;
insert into interests values('Business', 'your wildcard to determine business interest');
...one insert for each interest...

select t1.email, t2.interest, count(*)
from your_base_table as t1
join interests as t2
on t1.last_name like t2.wildcard
group by 1,2
qualify row_number() over (partition by email order by count(*) desc) = 1
```

Comment: While I'm not overly familiar with teradata I'm not sure this will actually solve this.  They want to return the max value from any of those columns, not convert the data into columns. BTW, not my downvote.

Comment: @dnoeth thanks for taking the time to answer. Where does the field "category" come from? PS not my downvote either

Comment: "Category" was just a guess :-) Could you post the query creating this result? I can check it tmmorrow

Comment: I could but would it be possible from the example data above? If the above table is called table1, how would one produce results that give just two columns: EMAIL and MAX Category across all fields? So:
duck@gmail.com | EntertainmentFashion

Comment: Changed "Category" to "Interest" ;-)  Everything is possible, but sometimes it's quite complicated, I'll edit my post.

Comment: Got it working now with the analytic function qualify, took a while but think I'm getting it. Thanks again